# Mongodb and php $nin query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

Please forgive my English in future updates.

I am experiencing problems mongodb php $nin query.

I can get a list of friend requests, but I can't get a list of 'not friends'.

sql:`Select * from uyeler where id NOT IN (select kime from ark where kim=$userid)`

**Friends request users:**

```
$uu = $ark->find(array('kim' => 0),array("kime" => 1,"_id"=>0)); // works
```

**NOT friends request**

```
$aa = $uyeler->find(array('id' => array('$nin' => array($uu)))); /// Doesn't work - shows same $uu (all friends, answer 1, 2, 3...)
```

Please have a look at look at:

[image: i.hizliresim.com/Dlgg56.png]

and

[image]

and my code

[image]

Comment: You passed in `$uu` as the argument to `$nin`. `$uu` is a cursor type - not the value that you want to put in. You want to extract the value of `kime` and put that as the value of the `$nin` key.

Comment: You can write a one example? like my code @wdberkeley

Comment: @wdberkeley ı understand you but how ı make this.